# How can I know if the save method worked in mongo

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

im new using mongo and when i save a new object in my db i use the save method, but when using it and then printing the result, if it was successful i get the object, not someting that i can use to handle any error in the front end

```
router.post("/post_recipe", async (request, response) => {
const {title, content, author} = request.body;
const new_post = new Posts({title, content, author});
new_post.save(sdfs).then((response) => {
    response.json(response);
  }).catch(error => response.json(error));
});
```

doing this on purpose i get the error in the console but its not sending it to the front end to handle it and tell the user that there was a problem

Posts its a scheme, dont know if it has something to do with

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are using same variable name for your router response and save method response.

**Solution**

```
router.post("/post_recipe", async (req, res) => {
const {title, content, author} = req.body;
const new_post = new Posts({title, content, author});

// Getting rid of .then and .catch method
new_post.save((err, savedPost) => {

  // Your custom error message
  if (err) return res.status(400).json('post not saved due to some problem! Please try again');

  // Post that you just saved in db
  return res.json(savedPost);
});
```

**This happen due to scope of variable.**

> For more detail [check this article](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) from w3schools.com

Comment: hi, thanks, but im trying to give an error on purpose and still doesnt send the error to front end